# wheezy-backports Release does no longer have a Release file

Tags: debian

Can someone help me with my Debian 9 Stretch problem? I just want to install nodejs but when I ran `apt-get update` I encountered these errors.

The first error is:

```
Err:11 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian wheezy-backports Release
404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.36.204 80]
```

The second error is:

```
E: The repository 'http://httpredir.debian.org/debian wheezy-backports Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
```

Please don't think of me as someone who has in depth knowledge of Linux, I'm a noob. All I just want is to be able to install `nodejs` and I'm stuck with this. Answers for dummies would be greatly appreciated thanks.

System info:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=debian
```

`sources.list`:

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://download.bareos.org/bareos/release/latest/Debian_9.0/ /
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch stable
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main
```

Files in sources.list.d:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 28 09:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Jun 28 09:32 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   75 Jun 28 09:09 docker.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   73 Mar  8 03:59 docker.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   62 Jun 28 09:30 httpredir_debian_org_debian.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   62 Jun 28 09:30 httpredir_debian_org_debian.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  112 Jun 28 09:32 nodesource.list
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wheezy backports are no longer available on the main mirror network, which is why `apt-get update` is giving you that error. The error doesn’t affect the rest of APT’s features, so you should still be able to install packages from your other configured repositories.

You shouldn’t need Wheezy backports on Debian 9, so the appropriate course of action to get rid of the error is to remove it from your configuration. I suspect the repository is defined in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/httpredir_debian_org_debian`, so move that out of the way:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/httpredir_debian_org_debian{,.bak}
sudo apt update
```